# Сделать чекбоксы в две колонки

Tags: javascript, html, css

как сделать чекбоксы в две колонки, не используя column-count. И чтобы при нажатии на кнопку More те чекбоксы, которые уже видны оставались на месте, а новые добавлялись снизу. Сейчас при нажатии на кнопку чекбоксы двигаются.

```js
(function() {
  var items = '.checkboxes__items';
  var hidden = '.checkboxes__item-hidden';
  var show = 'checkboxes__item';
  var btn_more = '.checkboxes__btn-more';

  $(btn_more).on('click', function() {
    $(items).find(hidden).each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass().addClass(show);
    });
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
  });
})();
```

```css
.checkboxes {
  color: #35373B;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.checkboxes__title {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 29px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.checkboxes__items {
  column-count: 2;
  max-width: 330px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.checkboxes__item {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.checkboxes__item-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes">
  <div class="checkboxes__title">Title</div>
  <div class="checkboxes__items">
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Education
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Weapon
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Comics
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Something
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Nation
      </span>
    </label>

    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        People
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Future
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        History
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item-hidden">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Politic
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item-hiddent">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Economy
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item-hidden">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Activity
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <button class="checkboxes__btn-more">
    + <b>More</b> (<span class="checkboxed__value">Num</span>)
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.checkboxes {
  color: #35373b;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.checkboxes__title {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 29px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.checkboxes__items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 330px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.checkboxes__item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}

.checkboxes__item-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function() {
  var items = '.checkboxes__items';
  var hidden = '.checkboxes__item-hidden';
  var show = 'checkboxes__item';
  var btn_more = '.checkboxes__btn-more';

  $(btn_more).on('click', function() {
    $(items).find(hidden).each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass().addClass(show);
    });
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
  });
})();
```

```css
.checkboxes {
  color: #35373B;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.checkboxes__title {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 29px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.checkboxes__items {
  /*************************/
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  /*************************/
  max-width: 330px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.checkboxes__item {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.checkboxes__item-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes">
  <div class="checkboxes__title">Title</div>
  <div class="checkboxes__items">
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Education
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Weapon
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Comics
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Something
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Nation
      </span>
    </label>

    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        People
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Future
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        History
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item-hidden">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Politic
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item-hiddent">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Economy
      </span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkboxes__item-hidden">
      <input class="checkboxes__input" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <span class="checkbox__label">
        Activity
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <button class="checkboxes__btn-more">
    + <b>More</b> (<span class="checkboxed__value">Num</span>)
  </button>
</div>
```